# Access Bitcoin Daemon from Another Server

Tags: php, bind, bitcoin, bitcoind

I have built Catcoind (a fork of the Bitcoin / project) and I can access the commands in my terminal by doing this from root:

```
cd catcoin/src 
./catcoind -daemon
```

That will start Catcoind, open the port, and allow me to type commands like './catcoind getdifficulty', but I want to access them from a PHP JSON-RPC client running on another server. The code I currently have there is:

```
<?php

require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php'; 

$catcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://RPCUSER:RPCPASS@IP:PORT'); 

print_r($catcoin->getinfo()); 
echo $catcoin->getdifficulty();
```

My config file for the Catcoind build on Ubuntu is:

```
server=1

rpcuser=USER

rpcpassword=PASS

rpcssl=0

rpcallowip=*

bind=IP:PORT

externalip=IP

proxy=IP:PORT

port=PORT

rpcconnect=IP
```

When I run the code, it says that it failed to open the stream / connection refused. The config for Catcoind is at location ~/.catcoin/catcoin.conf. Any ideas? I know this is confusing, but I have really everything done but allowing external IPs to access the API. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all these things to be written in conf file just use following

```
server=1
daemon=1
rpcuser=<user_namer>
rpcpassword=<password>
rpctimeout=30
```

if connecting from remote host do add following line

```
rpcallowip=<remote_ip_address>
```

save and exit from conf file and restart daemon by first stopping it catecoind stop and then catcoind start

Comment: I had to add
`rpcbind=0.0.0.0:8332` when using `rpcallowip`
But beware, don't use this outside your private network, the password is sent without encryption.

Comment: @ObjSal You just need `rpcbind=0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Are external IP allowed? If not make sure that the IP is allowed so that it can call the api. The error `failed to open the stream / connection refused` usually means that the ip and everything is correct but the server rejected the connection.

Comment: I thought I got it working by allowing access to the port the daemon was running on - Do I also need to 'forward' the IP somehow? Isn't that the function of 'bind'?

Comment: Is the catcoind on the server sending information to the second server or receiving?

Comment: It's receiving the RPC requests and sending the appropriate JSON response.